# SASS Variable in `url()`

Tags: webpack, sass, compass-sass

I have a variable which is a string to a image path:

```
$loader-path: "assets/loader.png";
```

I'm trying to use this variable as a background, however, I keep receiving an error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve "assets/loader.png"

This is what my SASS looks like:

```
$loader-icon: "assets/loading.png";

.inputLoader{
  background-image: url($loader-icon); // also tried url(#{$loader-icon})
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-left: -96px;
}
```

I have also tried the below, which is what [Compass](https://github.com/Snugug/training-glossary/wiki/Compass) pointed out:

```
background-image: image-url($loader-icon);
```

The above just prints `image-url(assets/loading.png)`

Comment: have you tried changing the path to absolute? like start it with `/`

Comment: Aah! Works perfect! Please do add an answer so I can mark this as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `/` in the path variable in order to make it absolute.
That error says that compass cannot find the resource you are linking to.

So, your variable would look like:

```
$loader-icon: "/assets/loading.png";
```